# How to pass a Java 8 lambda with a single parameter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to simply pass a lambda (chunk of code) and execute it when I need to. How do I implement the method `executeLambda(...)` in the code below (as well what is the method signature):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String value = "Hello World";
    executeLambda(value -> print(value));
}

public static void print(String value)
{
    System.out.println(value);
}

public static void executeLambda(lambda)
{
    someCode();
    lamda.executeLambdaCode();
    someMoreCode();
}
```

Comment: declare an `Functional Interface` with `executeLambdaCode()` method

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your lambda takes one parameter, but you only pass the lambda to `executeLambda`, not the value. If you want the lambda to capture the local variable, don't write it taking a parameter, but if you do really want it to take one parameter, you would write it like this:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String message = "Hello World";
    executeLambda(message, value -> print(value));
}

public static void executeLambda(String value, Consumer<String> lambda) {
    lambda.accept(value);
}
```

If you want it to capture the `value`, then use `Runnable`, write the lambda as `() -> print(value)`, and call it like `runnable.run()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String value = "Hello World";
    executeLambda(() -> print(value));
}

public static void print(String value)
{
    System.out.println(value);
}

public static void executeLambda(Runnable runnable)
{
    runnable.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By providing a reasonable parameter type. The method taking the lambda does not know about lambdas.

Instead you could pass a Callable object. And then your method has to invoke the call() method on that object! Alternatively, a Runnable or Consumer of String could be used (as a Callable is supposed to return a value - and the method you invoke is void).

Comment: `Callable` isn't the best choice here, since it doesn't expect a return value. `Consumer<String>` is a better choice.

Comment: I have been using Lambda's for a while and have actually passed my own, and have read a book on it. The challenge I'm having is that it's not very clear how to use your own, almost all the examples and information about Lambda's are about how to use them as parameters. For example how to pass a lambda to filter a stream, etc. Either way it's generally not good form to answer with a negative comment in an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Passing a byte[] and Runnable like:

```
public void doSmt(byte[] new_data, Runnable runnable) {
   for (byte datum : new_data) {
            LogI(String.valueOf(datum));
   }
   runnable.run();
}
```

Call:

```
byte[] new_data = new byte[10];    
doSmt(new_data, () -> {
     LogI("DA XONG");
});
```